# Apache Spark: StackOverflowError creating DataFrame in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, stack-overflow

I'm trying to get some tasks done with Apache Spark over two ArrayLists of my own classes. At the moment only locally for test purposes.

Therefore i have a GraphBuilder class whose constructor builds dataframes out of these ArrayLists. There are only some simple map or filter commands following.

```
//Constructor
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
nodes = deserializeNodes(pathToFolder);
edges = deserializeEdges(pathToFolder);

Dataset<Row> dfNodes = spark.createDataFrame(nodes, Node.class);
Dataset<Row> dfEdges = spark.createDataFrame(edges, Edge.class);
dfNodes.cache();
dfEdges.cache();
```

Due to the problem that im running into a java heapspace error with big datasets and problems with task size in spark i want to tweak my spark code to need less memory.

First things i noticed is the cache thing i want to remove if possible. But I'm getting into trouble with a StackOverflowError if I'm deleting the last cache() commands, but have no clue why i need them. Back then i used them simply because it worked... Note: with them everything works well until it gets more data so i have no clue why there should be an error writing the data.

**Could anyone please explain, why i need them cached or even better has an idea or workaround how i could repair my code?**

The following snippet is the error followed by my Node and Edge classes.

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$ReplaceTable.lookup(ObjectOutputStream.java:2399)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1113)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
//and so on and so on...
```

Node.java

```
public class Node implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1170671657280438989L;
    private String id; 
    private String pageId;

    public Node (String id, String pageId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.pageId = pageId;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPageId() {
        return pageId;
    }

    public void setPageId(String pageId) {
        this.pageId = pageId;
    }
}
```

Edge.java

```
public class Edge implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6419409809982356478L;
    private String src;
    private String dst;
    private String type;

    public Edge(String src, String dst, String type) {
        this.src = src;
        this.dst = dst;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getSrc() {
        return src;
    }

    public String getDst() {
        return dst;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean equals = false;
        if (o instanceof Edge) {
             Edge sp = (Edge) o;
             if (getType()==sp.getType() && getSrc()==sp.getSrc() && getDst()==sp.getDst()) {
                 equals = true;
             }
        }
        return equals;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ("<" + getType() + ">,<" + getSrc() + ">,<" + getDst() + ">").hashCode();
    }

    public void setSrc(String src) {
        this.src = src;
    }

    public void setDst(String dst) {
        this.dst = dst;
    }
}
```

Deserialize Methods:

```
private ArrayList<Node> deserializeNodes(String pathToFolder) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        ArrayList<Node> nodes = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(pathToFolder+"/nodes.tmp");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            nodes = (ArrayList<Node>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed deserializing. Please retry.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nodes;
    }

    private ArrayList<Edge> deserializeEdges(String pathToFolder) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        ArrayList<Edge> edges = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(pathToFolder+"/edges.tmp");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            edges = (ArrayList<Edge>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed deserializing. Please retry.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return edges;
    }
```

Comment: provide us `deserialize` methods implementations. tip: `StackOverFlow` exceptions generally occur when you recursively call functions or closures

Comment: added the code. but still have no idea who invoke an **output** stream and why caching is solving that.

Comment: The reason why caching exists is to not rerun the same code again hence a repeated implementation in your code is executed. Check it out carefully.